# How to access a pointer using 2 dimensional syntax?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to store `n * 2` values in some array.

I can easily do that like this

```
int n=5; //in real world this is calculated at runtime
int* arr;
arr = new int[n*2]
//fill arr with values
```

It's not a coincidence that I need `arr` to have n X **2** value and not simply n, `arr` stores pairs of values.
I could simply know what's stored and how, and access these pairs by offsetting the index by n,

```
cout<<"first  pair is"<<arr[0]<<","<<arr[n];
cout<<"second pair is"<<arr[1]<<","<<arr[n+1]
cout<<"last   pair is"<<arr[n-1]<<","<<arr[n+n-1]
```

But it would be so cool, if I could access these values as if they are in a 2 dimensional array, e.g.

```
cout<<"first  pair is"<<arr[0][0]<<","<<arr[0][1];
cout<<"second pair is"<<arr[1][0]<<","<<arr[1][1];
cout<<"last   pair is"<<arr[n][0]<<","<<arr[n][1]
```

The reason I'm not just declaring arr as a bidimensional array is that `n` is only known at runtime.

Can this be done in some way in C++?

Edit: I strongly prefer arrays over any other object structures for performance reasons. I know the performance differences is practically non-existent on modern computers, but this is my constraint. It has to still be just some integers stored in a contiguous piece of memory.

Edit about duplicate: The question that has been suggested as duplicate hits very close to home, although not exactly, but the answer to that question is just a workaround and not a direct answer. I would be happier to simply have an authoritative answer that it is not possible, rather than having alternative solutions. I am not looking for solutions, since I already have a solution in the question itself. I am looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v(5);` would allow `v[3].first` or `v.back().second`...

Comment: If you have pairs of data, why not have a vector/array of `std::pair`'s.?  `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: or `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> v(5);` if you really want `[]` syntax.

Comment: Notice that the way you access/arrange pair in your flat example is `a[0][n]`, `a[1][n]` and not `a[n][0]`, `a[n][1]`.

Comment: Why do you not use `int (*arr)[2] = new int [n][2];`?

Comment: Re “Everyone and everywhere it says that arrays are just pointers”: No, that is a false statement; not everyone and everywhere says that, and it is not true. Arrays are not pointers. We often use pointers to access arrays, and an array used in an expression other than as operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` (and possibly other places; the C++ rules may be complicated) is automatically converted to a pointer to help with this, but the array is not a pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil because I didn't manage to pinpoint the syntax. And honestly, I thought I've tried it like this already, but obviously I didn't. Yours is the correct answer. If you write this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as `2` is a compile time constant, you can easily do this in C++:

```
const int n = 7;
int (*arr)[2] = new int[n][2];
arr[2][1] = 42;
```

This declares `arr` as a pointer `*arr` to an array of two elements `(*arr)[2]` which are integers `int (*arr)[2]`. This new pointer is initialized with a suitable pointer allocated with `new`.

The parentheses around `(*arr)` are necessary because the array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`, and the parentheses force the correct order of operators.

Usage of the resulting pointer is exactly as you want, the memory is allocated in one piece, and you get rid of it with a simple

```
delete[] arr;
```

---

The compile-time-constant restriction is only present in C++, C is more lenient, allowing you to write stuff like

```
void foo(int width, int height) {
    int (*image)[width] = malloc(height*sizeof(*image));
    image[height-1][width-1] = 42;
    ...
```

where both dimensions of the 2D array are dynamic. C++ forbids this, forcing you to use compile-time sizes for all but the outermost dimension.

Comment: This is also the solution provided by @Eric in the comments of the question. I suggested him to write it as an answer, so that I can accept it as an answer, but that happened 35 minutes ago. I don't know what's the etiquette here. I am happy with your answer, but Eric came with it first, but as a comment instead of answer, but yours is also more complete. Since I am happy with your answer, should I accept your answer as the correct solution? I guess so, but I'll just delay taking this decision for a few more minutes :)

Comment: Actually, I wasn't aware of Eric's comment, I just jumped to the answers and saw that what I had to say was still missing there. The only real etiquette about marking an answer as accepted is, that one should wait 24 hours so that all users around the world may get a shot. If Eric writes a better answer than mine, that's fine with me, he'll get my upvote if I see it. In any case, a comment is generally not considered enough to answer a question: For one thing, comments are too short for real explanations, and for another, comments get deleted from time to time. Only answers persist.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks! I'll do as you suggest and come back tomorrow. The chosen answer will be the most complete variation of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare `arr` as a 2D array:

```
int n=5; //in real world this is calculated at runtime
int** arr;
arr = new int*[n]
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { arr[i] = new int[2]; } //each has two items

// ...

std::cout << "first  pair is" << arr[0][0] << "," << arr[0][1];
```

Or even better, you could use an `std::vector`:

```
int n=5; //in real world this is calculated at runtime
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n, std::vector<int>(2));

// ...

std::cout << "first  pair is" << arr[0][0] << "," << arr[0][1];
```

Or even better better, you could use an `std::vector` of `std::pair`:

```
int n=5; //in real world this is calculated at runtime
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr(n);

// ...

std::cout << "first  pair is" << arr[0].first << "," << arr[0].second;
```

Comment: Both of these methods of performance concerns.  None of the rows of data are guaranteed to be next to each other which can cause issues with cache performance.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way is to declare a vector of the type `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`.

For example

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v( n );
```

Otherwise you can dynamically allocate an array like

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::pair<int, int> *a = new std::pair<int, int>[n];
```

To access data members you can use expressions like  `a[i].first` and `a[i].second`.

Comment: If you're going to suggest `std::pair`, why use `new`?  Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe he does not yet know about std::vector.

Comment: That's a pretty poor excuse.  What if they don't know about `std::pair`?

Comment: @NathanOliver std::[air is very simple compared with standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

Or what about [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), you mentioned that you have pair of values what you can do is the following :

```
std::pair<int, int>* arr = new int[N];
// initialize your array :
// arr[i].first = x; arr[i].second = y; // or
// arr[i] = std::make_pair(x, y);
cout<<"first  pair is ("<<arr[0].first<<","<<arr[0].second<<")";
```

*first* and *second* fields are the first and second element respectively in your pair.
This solution will save you the time doing the O(N) loop for double pointers.

**Alternative better solution :**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr(N);
```

and then you can use the *operator[]* to access and set your elements.
This solution is better because it will manage the heap for you which will avoid leaks.

Comment: If you're going to suggest `std::pair`, why use `new`?  Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The user wanted for an array as he shows in his example but i edited my solution to have alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I think you should settle with a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` but here's another alternative that is safer than using raw `new`/`delete`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct mypair {
    int values[2];
    int& operator[](size_t idx) { return values[idx]; }
    int operator[](size_t idx) const { return values[idx]; }
};

int main() {
    size_t N = 10;
    std::unique_ptr<mypair[]> arr = std::make_unique<mypair[]>(N);

    arr[9][1] = 5;

    // arr is automatically deleted when it goes out of scope
}
```

Comment: If you're going to go that far, why not add some bounds checking on the `idx` you're passed to throw instead of causing UB?

Comment: @scohe001 OP seemed so concerned with performance that I even hesitated to use `make_unique` to initialize the array. Boundschecking would be a lot worse for performance.

Comment: Fair enough. As long as it was a conscious decision.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a class as the element of the array:

```
struct meaningfully_named_class {
    int meaningfully_named_member_first;
    int meaningfully_named_member_second;
};
// practical example
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::vector<point> arr(n);
cout<<"first  pair is"<<arr[0  ].x<<","<<arr[0  ].y;
cout<<"second pair is"<<arr[1  ].x<<","<<arr[1  ].y;
cout<<"last   pair is"<<arr[n-1].x<<","<<arr[n-1].y;
```

The advantage of using a custom class over using the `std::pair` template is the possibility of giving a meaningful name (as demonstrated) to the type as well as its members.

> I strongly prefer arrays over any other object structures

Just to clarify, `std::vector` is a container for a dynamically allocated array, and the integers in this case will all be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

To create an n×2 array of `int`, use:

```
int (*array)[2] = new int [n][2];
```